# Methanisation in the Haber Porcess

Tags: synthesis

I've been reading up on the Haber process lately.

In one such industrial case of ammonia synthesis, hydrogen is created through steam reforming, which creates some carbon monoxide. As the reaction continues, there exists both carbon monoxide and carbon dioxide.

In the final reaction chamber before the actual synthesis chamber, the Carbon monoxide and carbon dioxide are removed through methanisation - so it the majority (due to equilibrium) turns into water and methane.

My question is: how is the water and methane specifically removed without disturbing the remaining hydrogen and nitrogen?